# angularjs render data in multiple containers

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular. I am trying to find a way to render half of a data array into one div and the other one to another div.

```
angular.module("testApp", []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.data = [{name:'a'},{name:'b'},{name:'c'},{name:'d'}];
});
```

My template looks like this

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.name}}</li> // Render only <li>a</li> <li>b</li>
  <ul>

    <div> SOME OTHER CONTENT</div>
   <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data">{{item.name}} // Render only <li>c</li> <li>d</li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

I would like to use the same controller instead of using 2 different ones to render different content but i cannot make it work.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you,
Zaver

Comment: Although hacky, you could probably combine the two ng-repeats with ng-if and if the $index is less than data.length /2 show the content. And do the exact opposite for the second div.

Comment: Yes i thought about that but the div in between needs to live outside, separatelly of the two lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could use a custom filter to resolve this, for example:

**Custom Filter**:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(items, param1) {
    var end= param1 == 1 ? Math.floor(items.length/2) : items.length ;
    var start =  param1 == 1 ? 0 : Math.floor(items.length/2) ;
    console.log("param ",param1," start: ", start, " end: ", end);
    return items.slice(start, end);
    };
});
```

**Html**

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items|myFilter:1">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
<div>second have</div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items|myFilter:2">{{item.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Where in your filter `|myFilter:1` you set which half you want `1|2`.

> **Note:** I thought about using a notation like '50%>' and '<50%' instead of 1|2 looking for a interesting way to make the filter more clear and extensible with possibilities to do things like 25%<, 75%> but I wasn't sure if it was necessary in your scenario. Hopefully 1|2 will do the trick.

Here is [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/6QYVgeajYpfNaTkTFPrL?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [slice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) of the array to select the parts you give to the `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.slice(0, data.length/2)">
      {{item.name}}  // Render only a and b
    </li>
  <ul>

  <div> SOME OTHER CONTENT</div>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.slice(data.length/2)">
      {{item.name}} // Render only c and d
    </li>
  <ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you are coding on the view which is not recommended. The Angular way and also main reason to exist is the angular-filter.